# Security papers or material focusing on the industrial control systems (SCADA)

Tags: attack-prevention, attacks, incident-response, research, scada

Anyone know a good site or a list of resource to start to know issue related to the security of SCADA system ?

Answer (score 6):

For specific analysis of a particular attack in this space you should read the [Symantec Stuxnet paper](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/exploring-stuxnet-s-plc-infection-process) - gives good background as to just how badly a SCADA attack can compromise an industrial system.

Comment: Just FYI, ESET has analysed this attack first and they have comprehensive paper about this: http://blog.eset.com/2010/10/20/stuxnet-under-the-microscope-revision-1-11

Comment: @Ams - That one is pretty good. I hadn't seen it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Recently have stumbled upon SCADAPedia: http://www.digitalbond.com/wiki/index.php/Special:Allpages. I suppose, it could be useful.

Comment: Fantastic resource. There have also been a lot of talks at 2010 security/hacker conferences on SCADA-related subjects. [Here](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2434649448102709100) [are](http://www.defcon.org/images/defcon-18/dc-18-presentations/Arlen/DEFCON-18-Arlen-SCADA-Cyberdouchery.pdf) [a](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyXcHoVOBuc&feature=related) [few](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMVGP7SBeq8);

Comment: Yep, SCADA has gained a lot of attention in recent times.

Answer (score 3):

The US Department of Homeland Security and US-CERT maintain a great set of resources through their Control Systems Security program.  It includes security advisories and vulnerability bulletins as well as architecture best practices and other defensive strategies:

http://www.us-cert.gov/control_systems/index.html

It's a good introduction to the field.  I'd recommend starting there.

Comment: thanks, i'm starting check some material from UK web site about critical structures: http://www.cpni.gov.uk/default.aspx then i think i read some from your URL.

Answer (score 0):

I work in the control system security industry, so you can always follow me on Twitter (@mtoecker) for updates.

Additionally, there are several industry groups active in the area:

1. NIST's Computer System Resource center has some information: (csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsDrafts.html)
2. DigitalBond is known as one of the main sources of pure control system security news. http://www.digitalbond.com.  Dale also maintains a twitter account on @digitalbond
3. EnergySec is the DOE sponsored organization for control system security in electric power (www.energysec.org)
4. Bob Radvanovsky's Infracritical does an excellent job of news and a community through the SCADASEC mailing listserv http://www.infracritical.com/  (Look in the Mailing Lists heading)
5. ControlGlobal has posts and articles on security, though with a much more political and less technical viewpoint.  The 'Unfettered' blog is run by Joe Weiss, the grandfather of control system security   (community.controlglobal.com)

I hope this helps!

Mike Toecker
Private Citizen

/Currently limited to TWO hyperlinks.  :(